# json_encode add angle bracket < to the output

Tags: json, ajax

is there any reasone that make the json_encode add < before the output .

in php script: if the query is excuted successfully then php echo json_encode([]), but in the browser i got the following error:

```
VM341:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success
```

and the response is:

```
<{"status":"success","msg":"Your account was created successfully"}
```

my php code:

```
if ($result){  //$result is true
echo json_encode(['status' => 'success', 'msg' => 'Your account was created successfully']);
}
```

my ajax code is :

```
const accountForm = document.getElementById("accountForm");
........
type : 'POST',
url  : 'ajax/addaccount.php',
data : $(accountForm).serialize(), 
success : (response)=>{//debuger shows: response= "<{"status":"success","msg":"Your account was created successfully"}"
const convertedRes = JSON.parse(response);
if (convertedRes.status === "success"){
....
```

could you please help me finding out what could the problem be?! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

it looks fine for me

[image: look fine]

```js
const accountForm = document.getElementById("accountForm");

accountForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "script.php",
        data: $(accountForm).serialize(),
        success: (response) => {
            const convertedRes = JSON.parse(response)
            if (convertedRes.status === "success") {
                console.log(response);

            }
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: thanks, so there is no error in the code , i will check my php script again even though i already did it many times and my IDE does not show that there are typo error. i will right again if i found it out

Comment: I recommend using vs code or vs code insiders build with the php extension pack it's very good for php development and there is integrated debugging system Happ coding